# Heavy numbers calculation in Java

Tags: java, decimal

How to calculate heavy numbers in Java?

Heavy Decimal Count: A non-negative integer is called heavy if the average value of its digits in decimal representation exceeds 7. For example, the number is 9688, it has four digits i.e. Nine, Six, Eight, Eight (9,6,8,8). The average value of its digits is (9+6+8+8)/4 = 7.75. As the average value 7.75 is greater than 7, so we can say that 9688 is a heavy number. Now take another example, suppose given number is 41153. It has five digits i.e. 4,1,1,5,3. Average value of its digits is (4+1+1+5+3)/5 = 2.8. As the average value 2.8 is less than 7, so we can say that 41153 is not a heavy number. Now, it is required from you to write a function: heavyDeciCount(x,y)

The output should be like this please help on this topic.

```
Sample Output

Enter 1st integer: 9872
Enter 2nd integer: 9884
Number  Average Is Heavy
9872        6.50        No
9873        6.75        No
9874        7.00        No
9875        7.25        Yes
9876        7.50        Yes
9877        7.75        Yes
9878        8.00        Yes
9879        8.25        Yes
9880        6.25        No
9881        6.50        No
9882        6.75        No
9883        7.00        No
9884        7.25        Yes 
Total Heavy Count: 6
```

Comment: "it is required from you to write a function" .. it really looks like you just copied and pasted your homework here. please show us your effort and refine your question to a specific problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There's nothing tricky here. It doesn't even look like they care about the possible floating-point precision limit issues. The task is completely straightforward. Nothing here stands out as "the hard part", so it's difficult to tell what you need help with.

Comment: I need its solution in Java

Comment: Please help me. I am totally confused and stuck how to solve it. I need a complete solution of it

Comment: I just need Idea solution. I want to solve it myself

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

A function to calculate whether or not a number is heavy might look something like:
`public boolean isHeavy(int number) {`

```
String asString = "" + number;

 int sumOfDigits = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i <asString.length(); i++) {
     sumOfDigits += Integer.parseInt(asString.charAt(i) + "");
 }

 return (sumOfDigits / (double)asString.length()) > 7d;
```

`}`